# Python if/else statement in arcGIS

Tags: python, gis

I have this simple script in the Python window in the field calculator in ArcMap. If I take out the middle 'elif' statement, the code executes fine, but trying to run this with the elif statement causes it to fail "failure during geoprocessing".

```
 def myCalc(taxon):
    if taxon >329:
        return '1' 
    elif taxon <329:
        return '8' 
    else:
        return '9'

myCalc( !F18andUnd! )
```

Comment: What is `!F18andUnd!`?

Comment: that's being plugged into function.  it's the field referring to pop. 18 and under

Comment: And what is the question exactly?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: You'll find answers to this at the [gis.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: the question is: why is this failing with the elif statement?